# App only listens on localhost

Tags: localhost, putty

I'm trying to connect from inside the network to an app that only listens on localhost.

I can perfectly access it from the machine itself (obviously).

But cannot access it from another machine inside the network. Also obviously as localhost will direct to myself.

The thing is: it's all windows. So no linux to create an ssh tunnel.

I tried ngrok which works, but it's rediculous to first connect to a services to then come back to my own network. 
I tried, it works, but loses connection now and then.

So basically i want to setup the same thing as ngrok but completely locally.

Is this possible with putty?

Greetings and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a setting in the app which specifies on what port it listens. If you have something there like 0.0.0.0:4321 or localhost:4321 or 127.0.0.1:4321 change it to:

> *:4321

Also make sure:

- port is allowed in Windows Firewall,
- the app has privileges to listen on a port (as a test you can run it as Administrator),
- you can access your computer from the network at all - try accessing another program/service.

Comment: Hey piotrwest and thank you for your reply.

The thing is, the app only has an option to change the port. It auto binds itself to localhost. That's my issue here :)

Port is allowed in Firewall, that's no problem :)

Accessing the machine from another machine inside the network is also not a problem. It's that specific app that is bound to localhost that is a problem.

Thank you

Comment: I see, sorry - I've missed the question. In that case I would try setting a proxy/reverse proxy which would listen on *:4444 (different port than the original app) and forward requests to localhost:4321. Maybe you could try this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/use-putty-as-a-secure-proxy-on-windows/